# Compute the Fourier series of a piecewise function.

Tags: fourier-series

Consider the function:

$
 f(\theta) =
  \begin{cases}
   0 & \text{if } |\theta| >\delta \\
   1-|\theta|/\delta       & \text{if } |\theta| \leq \delta
  \end{cases}
$

I need to show that:

$$f(\theta)= \frac{\delta}{2\pi}+ 2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1-cos(n \delta)}{n^2 \pi \delta} cos(n\theta)$$

but the thing is that this integral $\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}( 1-|\theta|/\delta )e^{-in \theta}d \theta$ is a litle bit complicated for me because of the absolute value and how to make the substitution to integrate by parts, and the other thing is that $\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}( 1-|\theta|/\delta )d\theta \not= \frac{\delta}{2\pi}$

I dont know what I am doing wrong, Can you help me to complete this please?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: split the integral into two parts: $\int_{-\delta}^0$ and  $\int_0^{\delta}$..

Comment: Right I have done that, and I got the fourier coefficient for (0), but now I am triying to compute the nth fourier coefficient and I am a litlle bit stuck in the algebra jajajajaj

Comment: well everything comes down to calculating $\int \theta e^{-in\theta} d\theta$. For this you need integration by parts. Just follow the formalism...

Comment: Ok thanks a lot :)